# In Appium Python, how to press key code by key name?

Tags: python-appium

I am writing Python Appium code. The code needs to press the HOME button. Right now I have

```
driver.press_keycode(3)
```

where 3 is mapped to KEYCODE_HOME according to [keycode mapping](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_ENTER).

Is there a way that I can refer KEYCODE_HOME in my code so that my code is more readable?

I could have done the following:
adding a comment

```
# HOME Key is 3
driver.press_keycode(3)
```

or assigning a variable

```
home_keycode=3
driver.press_keycode(home_keycode)
```

But I'd more like to see something like

```
driver.press_keycode(AppiumKey.HOME)
```

Does such a thing exist?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can create Enum class and call variables like Keys.HOME etc

```
    class Keys(Enum):
        """
        List of keys
        """
        HOME = 3
    class PO(Base):
        press_key(Keys.HOME)
```

Or use an existing solution as well [python-client nativekey.py](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/644aa724b7939aae01bdcd055b0541bf879bde2b/appium/webdriver/extensions/android/nativekey.py#L16)

```
press_key(AndroidKey.HOME)
```

Comment: the 2nd option is what I was looking for. it worked!!!. thank you. I will provide an example below

Answer (score 1):

I use an example to substantiate Dmytro's answer

```
import appium.webdriver.extensions.android.nativekey as nativekey

androidkey = nativekey.AndroidKey
value = 'TAB' # use TAB key as an example

keycode = androidkey.__dict__.get(value, None)
print(f"key={value}, keycode={keycode}")

# driver init code is skipped
driver.press_keycode(keycode)
```